# Python - beautifulsoup: removing element inside specific tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, beautifulsoup

I'm using bs4 trying to get out data from the internet and I have to discard some elements if a condition is reached:

```
html_code = soup.findAll('tr', class_='class1')
```

I get:

```
<tr class=class1> <nobr><a href="link1.html">link</a> </nobr> text </tr>
<tr class=class1> <nobr><a href="link2.html">link</a> </nobr> text </tr>
<tr class=class1> <nobr><a href="link3.html">link</a> condition1 </nobr> text </tr>
<tr class=class1> <nobr><a href="link4.html">link</a> </nobr> text </tr>
```

I want to eliminate the element with "condition1" and keep the others

```
<tr class=class1> <nobr><a href="link1.html">link</a> </nobr> text </tr>
<tr class=class1> <nobr><a href="link2.html">link</a> </nobr> text </tr>
<tr class=class1> <nobr><a href="link4.html">link</a> </nobr> text </tr>
```

what is the best way to do it?

Another question.. is it better scrapy than bs4?

Comment: are you using soup to parse scrapy responses?

Answer (score 1):

You can  filter it like below

```
html_code = [x for x in soup.findAll('tr', class_='class1') if x.text.find('condition1') == -1]
```